# NameError when reordering for statements in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I'm learning list comprehensions and I am getting 2 different results by switching variables though they look like they should work the same.

An array `a` equals `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`

List Comprehension 1 Works:

```
[(i,j) for j in range(len(a[i])) for i in range(len(a))]
```

Returns:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4)]
```

As expected.

But flipping the variables...

```
[(j,i) for i in range(len(a[j])) for j in range(len(a))]
```

Results in a NameError:name 'j' is not defined

Can someone please explain to me why it matters whether i or j comes first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the order of the variables that matters here. In fact, running List Comprehension 1 does not work either, for the same reason as List Comprehension 2. I'm guessing you had defined `i` earlier in the program, which is why List Comprehension 1 worked for you. The problem is the order of the `for` loops.

I'll try to explain by example. If you were to write it like this, it would run fine:

```
[ [(i,j) for j in range(len(a[i]))] for i in range(len(a))]
```

Note the square brackets I added. In this case, the `for` loop with `i` happens first, and only then the `for` loop with `j`. (It should be noted, however, that this will return a list of lists of tuples.) Alternately, this would also run fine:

```
[(i,j) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(a[i]))]
```

When both `for` loops are written together that way (no extra brackets this time), they're read left-to-right.

Comment: You should mention that your first example, the nested list comp, creates a list of lists of tuples. Or just include its output in your answer.

Comment: OK makes sense, so in the first example, the for loop after the brackets would be the first to run? For example, if `ninecells=[[a[0][0]+w,a[0][1]+h] for h in range(-1,2) for w in range(-1,2)]` then the `for h in range` would run first?

Comment: @st4rgut With that example, `for h...` is the outer loop, and `for w ...` is the inner loop. In contrast, in `[[a[0][0]+w,a[0][1]+h for h in range(-1,2)] for w in range(-1,2)]`, we have a list comp nested inside another list comp, with `for w... ` being the loop for the outer list comp, and `for h...` being the loop for the inner one. So for each `w` an inner list (built using the `h` loop) is created.

Answer (score 6):

When you have a double `for` loop in a single list comprehension it's equivalent to doing those `for` loops in the same order using "traditional" `for` loops. So

```
result = [(j,i) for i in range(len(a[j])) for j in range(len(a))]
```

is (almost exactly) equivalent to

```
result = []
for i in range(len(a[j])):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        result.append((j, i))
```

As you can see, when you do `len(a[j])` the variable `j` doesn't exist, which is why you get that `NameError`.

BTW, your first list comp shouldn't work either. I suspect that you've defined `i` earlier in your code, which is why you don't get a `NameError`. Here's a slightly improved version of that list comp which assumes that `a` is a matrix, i.e., all of its sublists are the same length, and that it contains at least one sublist.

```
[(i,j) for j in range(len(a[0])) for i in range(len(a))]
```

We could also do

```
[(j, i) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(a[0]))]
```

Both of those list comps create this list:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4)]
```

Comment: Note: Neither listcomp should work, I suspect global or nested scope defines a variable named `i` though, and since the matrix is `n x n`, as long as `i` is a legal index, the use it's put to (to compute length of a `range`) works even though it isn't in the correct order.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Yes, I just noticed that myself. :) I'll mention that in my answer.